# Link to another page with ajax elements

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a website and I want to link page1 to page2:

Page2
-has a submenu which displays information like this:

```
$("#element").click(function(){
        $("#another_element").load("page3.html");
    });
```

on Page1, I have links, and I want to know if it is possible to have a href="page2.html/call_ajax_function_from_page2" with the ajax call. How can i click on an element in page1 and go to page2 an call it's load() so that it displays the info as if an element from its submenu were clicked?

Thanks!
**Additional info** By clicking an element in page1.html i want to redirect o page2.html with certain ajax content loaded to it. page2.html is the one with ajax

**More info:** I want to do this because on page1 I have a carousel, and each button I want it to link to a completely different page, page2 to display info relevant to that carousel. I have already built that page2 and it loads content based on .load when a link from its submenu was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong as your question is hard to understand, but I think you're looking for something along the lines of this:

```
$('#foo li a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#bar').load(href + ' #someContainer'); // Load the href + an ID.
    });
});
```

**So for example take this html:**

```
<ul id="foo">
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://microsoft.com">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apple.com">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you were to click link 2, the `preventDefault()` will 'prevent' your browser location from changing (changing page) then you will store the attribute of that anchor link in a variable called href. Then finally you will load the contents of that variable into your specified div, in this case 'bar'.

Comment: I DO want to go to a different page, but I want to go to differentpage.html/mission or something like that differentpage.html has a submenu and this has ajax, i don't know if it is possible to simulate an element from differentpage.html was clicked from mainpage.html. By clicking an element in mainpage.html i want to redirect o differentpage.html with certain ajax content loaded to it

Comment: @bb2 Do you mean like `$('#bar').load(href + ' #container');`

Comment: I don't want to load anything on the main page. On the main page I have a carousel and when you click a button I want it to go to another page and in that other page information is displayed via ajax